# Using cleveref with enumitem

Tags: enumitem, cleveref

I'm trying to reference a item with `\cref`  from a new list type created with `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside, openright]{book}
% Language options
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\selectlanguage{\english}

% Enable UTF-8 input
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\usepackage{glossaries}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[sf,outermarks]{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage[font=small]{caption}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listing}

\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,linkcolor=blue,urlcolor=orange]{hyperref}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\newlist{flatlist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[flatlist]{label={\textit{\alph*)}}}   


\crefname{flatlisti}{item}{items}
\creflabelformat{flatlisti}{#2#1#3}


\begin{description}
    \item [Dictionaries]  (i.e. words  \cref{gender_item}), and (i.e. usage count \cref{gender_data_item}).

    \begin{flatlist}
      \item Gender data \label{gender_data_item}
      \item Unigrams\label{gender_item}
    \end{flatlist}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

I get ??a) and ??b) references and the next Warning:

```
LaTeX Warning: cref reference format for label type `flatlisti' undefined on i nput line 22.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document ,not fragments only. (Putting all together and using `article` as document class, I get the correct references. Did you compile twice?)

Comment: Thanks for the help I put a full compilable document that fails. I provide the full packages in the same order. In case it is a package conflict. I use overleaf an I'm getting the correct bibliography. So i think is compiling two times.

Comment: Please put the `\newlist` and `\setlist` definitions as well as the `\crefformat` statements **before** `\begin{document}`. Also clean up the preamble. You're loading some packages twice and in the wrong order, but the main issue the wrong position of `\newlist` etc.

Comment: Please, avoid those slanted parentheses: `label=\textit{\alph*}\textup{)}` will yield a much better result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `\crefname` must be given always before `\begin{document}`, a specification later on will not work, since `cleveref` freezes its internal 'tables' of known counter names.

Following 'minimal' document has the same issue as from the OP: `\crefname{foolist}{foo}{foos}` is called too late here, unless shifted to `\begin{document}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\newlist{foolist}{enumerate*}{1}
\setlist[foolist,1]{label={\Roman*)}}

\creflabelformat{foolisti}{#2#1#3}

\crefname{foolisti}{foo}{foos}

\begin{document}

%%% Too late, see just before \begin{document}
%\crefname{foolisti}{foo}{foos}

\begin{description}
\begin{foolist}
\item A foo\label{foolabel}
\end{foolist}
\end{description}

However, see \cref{foolabel}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Put the ' \crefformat' statements after \begin{document} was the error. Thanks a lot! The other issues  comes from quick copy pasting.

Comment: What if you didn't create a `newlist` and instead just used `enumerate*` directly. What would `\crefname` look like in that case? What is an appropriate "name" for a `enumerate*` item?